# Want to know which excel formula can applied for order tracking one time full

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel

Want to make report which can track particular order is dispatched with all in one lot or multiple time from data sheet.

I could not able to find out which formula can applied for this. Please refer below data for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, add expected output and what have you tried. Also, add example input with [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: It's ain't a proper way to post a question here. You have to explain your question in more details and, what is most important, show your effords on solving it. But you came here with an order to do work for you. It looks same if i would say to you: "I want to be a millionaire, please refere to amount of $123 587 669.00 for your reference"